# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function how to fix this issue in react

Tags: reactjs

TypeError: Object(...) is not a function how to fix this issue in react

[image]

Comment: Please provide more details, and post your code

Comment: export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    firestoreConnect([
        { collection: 'project' }
    ])
)(Dashbord)

Comment: Error: Context from react-redux not found. If you are using react-redux v6 a v3.*.* version of react-redux-firebase is required.

Comment: const store = createStore(rootReducers,
     compose( 
         applyMiddleware( thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
        
         reduxFirestore(fbConfig),
         reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig)
         
    ));

Answer (score 3):

Your problem seems to be that either you didn't import the `react-redux-firebase` properly, or are using a backdated version of it. Your second comment states

```
Error: Context from react-redux not found. If you are using react-redux v6 a v3.*.* version of react-redux-firebase is required.
```

It is evident that a correct version is not installed probably. One possible solution is to downgrade your version of React and react redux firebase using this npm commands:

```
npm -i --save react-redux@5.1.1

npm -i --save react-redux-firebase@2.2.4
```

These versions are stable and better to work with as react redux firebase version 3.* is not stable and is not auto downloaded for React redux version 6.* when installing the regular way with `npm`, has to be manually installed using `npm i --save react-redux-firebase@latest`

Once you downgrade, please restart your application using `npm start` to see the changes.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading the react-redux-firebase to v3 you have to do these certain changes in root file index.js

```
...
import { createFirestoreInstance } from 'redux-firestore';
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider } from 'react-redux-firebase';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "apiKey",
    authDomain: "authDomain",
    databaseURL: "databaseURL",
    projectId: "projectId",
    storageBucket: "storageBucket",
    messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.firestore();

const store = createStore(rootReducer,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(
            thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })
        ),
        reduxFirestore(firebase),
    )
);

const config = { useFirestoreForProfile: true, userProfile: 'users', attachAuthIsReady: true };

const rrfProps = {
    firebase,
    config,
    dispatch: store.dispatch,
    createFirestoreInstance
}

const app = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <App />
                </BrowserRouter>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
    </Provider>
)
ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
```